# SharePoint 2013 NTLM authentication 403 Forbidden in POST request

Tags: ntlm

I use NTLM security for SharePoint 2013 on-premises. I can get all the lists of its site with username and password but I get 403 Forbidden for this NTLM security.

The error shows:

> "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."

I tried some with "X-RequestDigest: digest" but not working either with libcurl.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I got it. Add the user and give it full permission in IIS Security -> SharePoint.